# Prevent recursive exclusion of folder with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

We are getting stuck with excluding a particular folder from our deployment. Currently, our deploy script contains the following line:

```
<Exec Command='"@(MSDeploy)" -verb:sync -source:package="$(Source)" -dest:iisApp=$(iisAppName),computerName=$(WebServerName),username=$(UserName),password=$(UserPswd) -skip:Directory=\\Logs -skip:Directory=\\Prototype -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="Resources"'/>
```

If you scroll to the end of the snippet above, you will see the following:

```
absolutePath="Resources"
```

Ideally, we want to exclude one particular folder but didn't know how to specify this absolute path.

Previously, this wasn't creating major issues but now within our project, we have other "resources" folders and we need them to be deployed. Can anyone help with how to either specify the absolute path or to prevent recursive exclusion of the folder?

So our folder structure is something like this:

```
- Web site
  - Resources (Should not be deployed)
  - Front end
    - Resources (Should be deployed)
```